# nginx error_page is not working with nodejs server

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect the 502 error of a nodejs server to maintenance page. Here is my nginx config:

```
  location /50x.html {
        root /var/www/html/maintenance.html;
        }
  location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;

   }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
```

but no luck, it still returns `502 Bad Gateway`. What is wrong and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the '/var/www/html/maintenance.html' in  'location /50x.html' context a directory or just a html file?

You are supposed to put a 50x.html in /var/www/html/ if you want the server to locate the 50x.html. and change the configuration as follows:

```
location /50x.html {
        root /var/www/html;
        }
```

Comment: I updated to  and changed the file name, restarted nginx, it still doesn't work

Comment: @LeDuyKhanh Would you post the error logs and the access logs of the web server up here? Thanks.

Comment: 122.11.149.178 - - [11/Sep/2017:13:11:24 +0800] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"
122.11.149.178 - - [11/Sep/2017:13:11:24 +0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "https://stage.spectrum.global/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"